# OpenGL lighting don't work

Tags: opengl, lighting

I'm trying to setup lighting in my scene
but for some reason it doesn't work, i'm trying to figure out why

here's how I initialize OpenGL:

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClearDepth(1.0);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

and here is how I try to draw with lighting on:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glLoadIdentity();
GLfloat diffuse0[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat ambient0[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat specular0[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat light0_pos[]={1.0, 1.0, 1,0, 1.0};

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_pos);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular0);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 2.0);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 1.0);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 2.0);

object->draw();
```

the object is not affected by the lighting at all

all normals are set and all the information that opengl require for lighting a scene

is there... what am I missing?

EDIT: 
OK! I finally found a solution to the problem.
my opengl init function was misplaced in the code
I had to call it after showing the window and not before 
and that's what caused the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should tell us the position of the object.

- Suspect 1: The position of the object and the light are too far
- Suspect 2: Hide all ATTENUATION settings or make LINEARATTENUATION to 0.0

Comment: the object is at (0.0, -15.0, -20.0) I also checked what happens when the object is at (0.0, 0.0, -6.0) but I get the same results
about the second suggestion.. I tried to do as you said but it still don't work